# Is it still possible to check login sessions in an invisible iframe?

Tags: firefox, cookies, openid-connect

For OpenID Connect, a common technique is to use a hidden iframe to login with prompt=none, to restore the user's session without having to redirect to the provider. Once tracking cookies are disabled by the upcoming Firefox release, will this technique still be possible? How do I convince Firefox to send cookies when loading an iframe from another site?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox displays a shield icon in the address bar when it is blocking content, like cookies. Some sites are smart enough to ask you to allow certain  if their login fails, and it is relatively easy to do so by clicking on that icon.